# Javascript: change function from On^2 to On - find integers between identical integers in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```js
// Write a function that returns integers between identical integers
var input = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2]
// output = [3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5]

const identical = (input) => {
  let returnValue = [];
  
  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
    for (var j=i+1; j<input.length; j++ ) {
        if (input[i] === input[j]) {
        returnValue = returnValue.concat(input.slice(i+1, j));
        j = input.length;
      }
    }
  }
    return returnValue
}

console.log(identical(input));
```

I have been staring at this and cannot figure out a data type that will let me solve this with a single walk through of the array. Any help would be appreciated.

This was a coding exercise I encountered and could only figure it out for On^2.

Comment: why are there two 4s in the desired output?

Comment: because 4 is between two 2's and two 3's

Comment: in that case the size of the output is O(n^2) in the worst case, so you can't expect better time complexity than that.

Comment: Started to type my answer before @MattTimmermans comment's. But yes, that is, in one line, what I meant in 30.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly interpreted the task? Can you provide a source?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some element of context to share (for example that the values of the array are among a very restricted set of possibilities ; or that you are mentioning "average case scenario" which some hint on how those number are, randomly, but according to a known stochastic distribution, chosen), in absence of such knowledge, so, the answer is "can't be done".

Very concrete argument: let's consider the case where input contains `[1,2,3,...,n,1,2,3,...,n]`.

So, input size is 2n.

And output in this case is size n×(n-1).
Or, if you prefer, calling N the size of input (N=2n ⇒ n=N/2), output size has len `N/2×(N/2-1)`. Which is `O(n²)`.

Any algorithm producing such an output has to be at least O(n²), just for its fabrication.

Maybe, with another data structure for output, for example, one that list slices of input, by referring not the values, but the boundaries, it can be possible. Not even sure of that. For example, keeping a list of potential starting/ending point would need to search in this list, which can't be done in O(1), unless you index an array with the data itself, or a given unique-hash of this data; but can't count on that without knowing constraint on the possible value of the data. But well, maybe there is an algorithm I am not aware of that could list the slices in O(n).

So if the objective was just to list the slice, my proof that O(n²) is the minimum wouldn't stand (which wouldn't proof that it is possible to do better. Just that there is no proof that it is impossible).

But in the meantime, what you've asked for, is an algorithm that returns an array of the numbers enclosed in identical numbers. That can't be done in less than O(n²), in absence of more knowledge on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Makes me feel better that I'm not losing it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object for seen values and store values in previous seen keys. If key is seen again, the store items ar added to the result set.

```
[2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2]  
    3  4
       4  2
             3  5
```

```js
const
    input = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2],
    open = {},
    result = [];

for (const value of input) {
    result.push(...(open[value] || []));
    Object.values(open).forEach(a => a.push(value));
    open[value] = [];
}

console.log(...result);
```

Another approach by storing indices.

```js
const
    input = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2],
    open = {},
    result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const value = input[i];
    if (input[open[value]] === value) {
        while (++open[value] < i) result.push(input[open[value]]);
    }
    open[value] = i;
}

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking. Although you have to loop through the open object each time and if there are no matches then the worst case is still On^2,  right? If there are guaranteed identical integers then I think this is the best you can do.

Answer (score -1):

if you know your numbers in a list are `m` bit integers (or have max value `M`) you could do a histogram based approach in `O(n+2^m)` or `O(n+M)` time complexity and `O(2^m)` or `O(M)` space complexity (with two passes over input array). As `m` is constants and or `M` usually linearly scales with `n` then it leads to `O(n)` result

1. compute histogram `O(n)`
2. for first entry in histogram with count>=2 produce output

something like (C++ typed directly in here so it might contain typos):

```cpp
const int input[] = { 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2 };
const int inputs = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
int output[inputs-2];
int outputs = 0;
int hist[1<<m],i,x;

// compute histogram 
for (i=0;i<(1<<m);i++) hist[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<inputs;i++) hist[data[i]]++;
// find first multiple integer
for (i=0;i<(1<<m);i++)
 if (hist[i]>=2)
    {
    // produce output and stop
    x=hist[i]; outputs=0;
    for (i=0;input[i]!=x;i++);
    for (i++;input[i]!=x;i++){ output[output]=input[i]; outputs++; }
    // here output[outputs] hold your answer
    break;
    }
```

you could have just 2 bits per entry in histogram to spare memory using just values

- 0 (not present)
- 1 (present once)
- 2 (present 2 or more times)

in such case it would be:

```cpp
// compute histogram 
for (i=0;i<(1<<m);i++) hist[i]=0;
for (i=0;i<inputs;i++)
 if (hist[data[i]]) hist[data[i]]=2;
  else hist[data[i]]=1;
```

once you pack 4 x 2 bit counters into single `uint8_t` then full range 32bit integers will lead to 1 GByte histogram which is manageable these days however your array suggest that your integers are in range `0..M` where `M = ~ n` so in such case you need just some margine of error like `M = n + (n>>3)` histogram size ... or scan it with another pass

in case you have also negative integers you need to shift the indexes into non-negative values with some bias (like `1<<(m-1)`)